# Using Private Static Boolean

Tags: java, static, private

I am a brand new student of java and I have been searching google and my textbook to figure out what exactly it means to use a private static boolean, though none of it is really making any sense so I figured I'd ask the experts. My problem is that I need to use the private static class, though I don't know how to draw the data I need from main (which was kindly already written by my professor). Do you have any suggestions or insight? I'm basically converting code that I have already written in the form of nested loops into a private class.

edits:
this is what I have to work with (I'm not looking for a handout)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Foo
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{

    int lo = 0;
    int hi = 0; 
    String infileName; 

    if (args.length < 3)
    {
            System.out.println("CMD LINE INPUT ERROR: Must enter 2 numbers followed by name of input file on cmd line.");
            System.exit(0);
    }

    lo = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    hi = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    infileName = args[2];

    for( int n = lo; n<=hi; n++)
        if (isPrime(n))
            System.out.print(n + " ");
    System.out.println();

    for( int n=lo; n<=hi; n++)
        if (isPerfect(n))
            System.out.print(n + " ");
    System.out.println();

    while (infile.ready()) 
    {
        String line = infile.readLine(); 
        if ( isPalindrome( line ) )
            System.out.println( line + " IS a palindrome");
        else
            System.out.println( line + "is NOT a palindrome");
    }
    infile.close();

} 

}
```

the assignment is in three parts: finding prime numbers, perfect numbers, and palindromes.
for an example of part 1, I have previously used the following to find prime numbers

```
for(int i= lo; i < hi; i++)
        {

            boolean isPrime = true;

            for(int j=2; j < i ; j++)
            {

                if(i % j == 0)
                {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(isPrime)
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
```

I'm mostly not sure how to apply what I already know in a new way.

Comment: please post the code and be a little bit more specific about the question.

Comment: Yes, we need more information to help you properly. I don't know how people are answering this question as it stands.

Comment: do you mean private static method ?? cuz private static class cant be true

Comment: I'm sure I do, I'm not well acquainted with the terminology yet

Comment: Which brand you are from ?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you mentioned **private static class**, you can have a **static inner class**. but you cant mark a class(outer class) with **private modifier** i.e., you cant have a **private class** (outer class).
outer Classes can only be marked with **public** or **final** or **abstract** or **default(no modifier)**

**private static boolean:**

**private** is an **access modifier** which can be used for instance variables and methods.
private variables and private methods are only confined that the class which they were declared in.

**static** is an **non access modifier** which can be used for variables and methods.static variables are shared by all instances of a class.

**boolean** is a **primitive datatype** which can be true or false.

if you declare a boolean variable as private static like

```
  class MyClass {
       private static boolean bool;
   }
```

1. this bool variable can only  accessed from with in the class(MyClass) which it is defined.

2.All the instances created for this class(MyClass) share this bool variale.

Comment: I disagree. Inner classes in java can be marked private. Your generalization is inoccrect.

Comment: I don't think you understood what I said. I am pointing at this sentence "you cant have a private class" which is wrong. Now read my comment again as to why.

Comment: That's exactly what is wrong my friend. Inner classes can be private. You are saying classes in Java can't be private. That's why I am asking you not to generalized or be Moe specific. Is my English really that bad :)

Comment: @bot just to make it clear, i know that high level classes(outer classes) cant me maked private, but inner class can .. sorry if my generalization is confusing ?..

Comment: @bot... sorry, i am still half asleep .. i mentioned in my above comment ... and btw, your english is prefectly alright .. :)

Comment: Exactly my friend. You need to edit your post to say that outer classes can't be private. Saying classes can't be private is a generalization that is wrong.

Comment: @bot you are write, i should have mentioned high level classes(outer classes) in the answer .. thnaks :)

Comment: Your welcome. Just making sure people don't make assumptions when they are starting out. I used to think local variables and instance variables are the same when I was young :)

Comment: @bot haha, i dint include class types(inner, outer) cuz, i dint want to confuse the OP as he is still beginner. :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not take data from main, main jumps to other functions and passes the required data to them.  If you're talking about member variables, basically just move what is currently local, but used more than once to just under the class block and not in any function.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the word "class" is confusing, although I believe you actually mean "method" rather than "class"

By "private static boolean" I'm guessing you're talking about the *header* of a *method* which is a block of code and can be called (invoked) at any point in a program. A method often takes in a certain amount of parameters and often, but not always, returns a value.

private: restricts the method's use to the *class* it is defined in.

static: a method which is static can be accessed directly by the class name and doesn’t need any object, i.e. ClassName.methodName() vs. ObjectName.methodName().

boolean: simply means that a *boolean* value is returned by the method.

your code might look something like this:

```
private static boolean isBiggerThanZero( int number)
{
    boolean isBigger = false;

    //Do something with number or test it for a condition
    if( number > 0 )
        isBigger = true;

   return isBigger;
}
```